# Firebase - Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.uid'

Tags: angular, firebase

I am currently learning Angular by using this book called "Hands-On Full Stack Development with Angular 5 and Firebase'. I have followed the book but am currently facing an error when I click on the sign up button. However, the email and password used to sign up will be shown in the Authentication tab.

I know that userInfo.uid is not returning the uid but I am not sure why since I am following exactly what the book has taught me. I've even looked at the source code online but can't seem to wonder why.

**signup.component.ts**

```
onSignup(signupFormData): void {
    this.authService.signup(signupFormData.value.email, signupFormData.value.password).then((userInfo) => {
        // Register the new user
        const user: User = new User(signupFormData.value.email,
            signupFormData.value.name, signupFormData.value.mobile, userInfo.uid, 0, '');
        this.writeNewUser(user);
        this.navigateToUserProfile();
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.showError = true;
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}

private writeNewUser(user: User): void {
    this.userService.addUser(user);
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
public addUser(user: User): void {
    this.fireDb.object(`${USERS_CHILD}/${user.uid}`).set(user);
}
```

Comment: Did you console.log(signupFormData.value), I guess email or password in undefined and firebase cannot insert undefined as email address

Comment: @MH-Li nope, no issue with both email and password. I can see both values

Comment: Can you post the code on writeNewUser function? Something is happening over there. And please do console.log('userInfo.uid',userInfo.uid) and console.log('user', user),  the line before this.writeNewUser(user);

Comment: @MH-Li i've edited my post and added in the required codes

Comment: Do you use firebase realtime data base or firestore ?

Comment: @MH-Li realtime database

Answer (score 0):

In addUser function, If you are using Firebase realtime database you can insert new user like this:

```
const userObject ={"eamil":email, "createDate":'xxxx',....}
admin.database().ref('/users').child(uid).set(userObject)
```

If you are using firestore change code like this:

```
firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).set(userObject);
```